# Fastest Multivariate KDE Method

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, kde-plasma

I have a dataset of ~3x10^7 points in five dimensions, for which I must calculate:

- One KDE model for the total dataset;
- Fifty models for a subset of 1% of the entries.

I am doing this to follow the method outlined in this paper, for an N-Dimensional Kolgromov-Smirnov Test for highly correlated, non-linear data [paper here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C030908/papers/WEJT001.pdf).

What is the fastest option I have available to me to achieve this, assuming computing resources are not a constraint?

I am aware I can parallelize the loop over the fifty subsamples, however, I am keen to know what KDE methods are available to me.

Specifically, I am interested in:

1. Options for kernels that will speed up the process;
2. Parallellized methods - I have many cores available to me.
3. Other options I have missed that might make the procedure quicker, yet maintain enough accuracy for a statistical test.

At the moment I am naively using scikit-learn. I cannot do a scan of the bandwidth because the procedure is intrinsically far too slow. I am therefore guessing as to the bandwidth size in the following example:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
N = int(3e7)
N_smp = int(np.around(0.01*N, 0))

data = np.random.rand(N,5)
kde = KernelDensity()
kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.01)
kde.fit(data)

kde_smps = []

for i in tqdm(range(50)):
    data_smp = np.random.choice(data, N_smp, replace=False)
    kde_smp = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.01)
    kde_smp.fit(data_smp)
    kde_smps.append(data_smp)
```